# Traefik basic configuration for running in a Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik, swarm, docker-swarm-mode

From what I can see it goes like [this](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/733e100fe0313686f462283cee0139b1):

`docker-traefik.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: --docker   # enable Docker Provider
      # use Docker Swarm Mode as data provider
      --docker.swarmmode
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      # for it to be able to listen to Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

`docker-whoami.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
  traefik_default:
    external: true

services:
  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    networks:
      # add to traefik network
      - traefik_default
    deploy:
      labels:
        # whoami is on port 80
        - "traefik.port=80"
        # whoami is on traefik_default network
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_default"
        # when to forward requests to whoami
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.com"
```

Let me quote the [documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#using-docker-with-swarm-mode) here:

> Required labels:
>
> - `traefik.frontend.rule`
> - `traefik.port` - Without this the debug logs will show this service is deliberately filtered out.
> - `traefik.docker.network` - Without this a 504 may occur.
>
> ...
>
> `traefik.docker.network`  Overrides the default docker network to use for connections to the container. [1]
>
> `traefik.port=80` Registers this port. Useful when the container exposes multiples ports.

But why can't it just take the exposed ports for a default value of `traefik.port`? And from what I can see it works without `traefik.docker.network` (that is, if `traefik_default` is the first service's network). When do I get 504's?

Answer (score 0):

> But why can't it just take the exposed ports for a default value of traefik.port?

If ur container has 3 or 4 exposed ports, which should traefik use? So who saying to traefik, which of these ports the right one? So you do - with `traefik.port`. Where is the problem to use the default port of your configured service?

U should expose 80, 443 and 8080 - so 80 and 443 for http/https webpages and 8080 for traefik dashboard. If u dont wanna use the dashboard, u dont need to expose 8080.

And i dont see any network configured @ traefik in your composer file - should this have no network? Ur service and traefik need to be in the same network. Otherwise traefik cant reach ur service and forward.

Also where are the endpoints?

Comment: But it somehow figures out the network if `traefik.docker.network` is not specified. Why can't it do so with `traefik.port`? Then, read the question carefully. It says "basic configuration." Meaning settings without which it doesn't work. As such, I need to expose only port 80. Also, take a closer look, they're on the same network. Just run those two `yaml` files and see for yourself.